# Can't configure SynapticsTouchpad

Tags: drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have an ultrabook from a computer-building factory (it's not name brand),
and I run Ubuntu 14.04.

I lack options for deactivating touchpad while typing and activate two-finger-scroll and I am also unable to use synclient to edit the touchpad features.

Here's the output from xinput:

```
ina@laptop:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is what happens when I try to run synclient:

```
ina@laptop:~$ synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

When i check the software center I can see that i have this package installed:
*xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid*

List of things I've tried:
- Reinstalled *xserver-xorg-input-synaptic-lts-vivid*
- Installed both *tpconfig*, *kde-touchpad* and *gpointing-device-settings*
- Copied 50-synaptics.conf from /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d (but I had to create this folder).

**Touchpad**
Partnr: 640901100105
Name: TS - U731 - Touchpad BYD BTP10463-212 A2 Mutual Capacitance Multi-Finger CX11 NPB

Answer (score 0):

Linux 4.6 now treats BYD touchpads as touchpads, see [patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/2/3/15).

However it's not supported by synaptics yet as of xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.8.2 (current version in xenial), so `synclient` and other GUI tools (e.g. the KDE `kcm_touchpad` system settings module) cannot configure the touchpad behavior yet.

The issue is tracked [as launchpad #1424293](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1424293).